# How do I write a package that can be imported with just 'name' instead of 'name.name'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, setuptools

I've read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), and I'm still unclear on how to use setuptools to create a package / module that doesn't require my users to import a double name:

```
import myModule.myModule as mm
```

I want to create a separate and independent package to be installed with just `myModule`:

```
import myModule as mm
```

My package / module is very simple and just has one file:

```
mymodule (git directory)
--> setup.py
--> myModule (directory)
----> __init__.py
----> myModule.py
```

I just want to have this one file installed in site-packages so that my users can just run `import myModule`.

Comment: What happens when you just use ```import myModule```?

Comment: Can you show your project file structure and `setup.py`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Packages need an `__init__.py`. What file name(s) and folder layout you are using?

Comment: I edited the original question, thank you for the feedback

Comment: Do you plan on adding more modules to your package? If not, don't make it one — just make `MyModule.py` a normal module.

Comment: I don't plan on adding more; how do I use setuptools to distribute a module instead of a package?  I don't want to have to make users figure out where their python libraries are located to copy my file to it.

Comment: If you want to distribute `myModule.py` as a standalone module, then don't put it in a `myModule` package in the first place. Move it to the same level as `setup.py`, fix the imports, verify the tests work, remove `packages` keyword from `setup()` function and add `py_modules=['myModule']`.